# filter a dataframe based on partial string values that also have special characters

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I am trying to filter a dataframe based partial strings in the dataframe column that would match with the list of values i have in a list.

The issue is that some of the matching strings have special characters in them,
Eg:

```
=OEAKPOB|2OEAQPYA0402343|@@EAY632|@@EAY6XF3260| LD93684589|4+EB484K|4+EB481W|4*EBEWRX||=OEAKQJW|VNEAKX74
```

and when i try

```
pat = '|'.join(criteria_filter['ID'])
df_B = detfile_df[detfile_df['ID'].str.contains(pat)]
```

I get a

```
error: nothing to repeat
```

Now i guess this is due to a bug or the inability of my two line code above to deal with special characters.

Can you help on how i can fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape special regex characters by `re.escape` in generator comprehension:

```
import re
pat = '|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in criteria_filter['ID'])
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, A similar question..
If i have string starting with special character in my dataframe, and i write this df to csv, will the output in csv get modified to 0/ blank ? (especially string starting with = sign, as = is treated as formula start ?

Comment: @asimo - Not sure if understand, can you be more specific with sample data?

Comment: @asimo - because if starting strings by `=` it is not special regex character, so no problem with it

Comment: sure let me check and revert accordingly